# unable to logging in using php

Tags: php, authentication

While the same concept is working on other forms for log in function, I'm unable to do so. Help me in login and register. Unable to execute this. Here is code of login and register form and hlater login.php page which should be used for login and register to database. All details are in the code. And kindly report the error and further modification require. Thanks in advance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  -->
        <title>Login and Registration Form T & P Cell</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <meta name="description" content="Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="html5, css3, form, switch, animation, :target, pseudo-class" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate-custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Codrops top bar -->
            <div class="codrops-top">

                <span class="right">

                </span>

            </div><!--/ Codrops top bar -->

            <section style=" height: 480px">                
                <div id="container_demo" >

                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form" style=" height: 270px">
                            <form  action="login.php" method="POST" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" />
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                                             <p class="login button" style="float: left">

                        Not a member?           <a href="#toregister" class="to_register"  > Join Us                                                                                                     </a>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
                                </p>

                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div id="register" class="animate form"  style=" height: 400px">
                            <form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u"> Full name</label>
                                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text"  />
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" /> 
                                </p>
                                 <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" />
                                </p>



                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password"/>
                                </p>

                                <p class="login button" style="float: left">
                                Already a member ?
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                                </p>

                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>




        <?php
    session_start(); // Starting Session
    $error = ''; // Variable To Store Error Message
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "string6";
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo "gh";
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        } else {
            echo "asdfgh";
            // Define $username and $password
            $username   = $_POST['username'];
            $password   = $_POST['password'];
            // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
            $username   = stripslashes($username);
            $password   = stripslashes($password);
            $username   = mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
            $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
            // Selecting Database
            $db         = mysqli_select_db("tandp_db", $connection);
            // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
            $query      = mysqli_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
            $rows       = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if ($rows == 1) {
                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; // Initializing Session
                header("location:login.html"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            } else {
                $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
            }
            mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: probably `headers already sent`?

Comment: actually .. php code not working ... means unable to perform any of php operation

Answer (score 0):

in php code below in your script, you are checking this :  if (isset($_POST['submit'])), so in the login form give name to submit button : 
    `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />`